# jwplayer won't play a .3gp file made on an EVO (running Android)

Tags: jwplayer

I embedded the jwplayer and it plays a sample .mp4 video that came with the jwplayer installation.

According to my understanding, jwplayer should play a small .3gp video 
with no issues.

So I created a test case .3gp video on my EVO running Android.

I loaded this file onto my Windows Vista laptop and verified my sample .3gp video file was
good by playing it in QuickTime -- no problem, video is good.

However, when my jwplayer appears on my web page, I press 'play' and the 'Waiting...'
indicator just sits there and spins and spins.

Do I need to 'process' my .3gp video file somehow before playback in jwplayer?
I think the answer is 'No' based on the 'supported video formats' for jwplayer they
indicate on the jwplayer website:
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that despite a (possibly self-interested?) recommendation from here on SO, the jwplayer folks
perhaps have lost interest in supporting their open-source jwplayer, as their forum reflects dissatisfaction
with my issue here and others.  It seems to be a common complaint on their forum that the jwplayer has noteworthy
shortcomings.  Including:

- will not work on the Mac OS X  at all
- does not work with 3gp either, despite their 'tech notes' claims to the contrary

I found recurring complaints along these lines.  With 3gp being very common, and the Mac OS
being no slouch either, I would strongly advise those of you contemplating use of the jwplayer
to look elsewhere as we are doing now for our video playing needs.